# How to show shapefile on map in python?

Tags: python, shapefile

I am currently working with python and using basemap to draw Vietnam's map like this :
[Vietnam's Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsuYc.png)

My shapefile : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJxzd.png)

I want to show all island groups or small islands by using shapefile I've had already but I have no idea to read shapefile. I've tried some code on the Internet but it did not work. I hope you guys can help me. I really appreciate. Thanks a lot.
This is my code :

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from cartopy.feature import ShapelyFeature
from cartopy.io.shapereader import Reader
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np
plt.figure(figsize=(12,7))
m = Basemap(projection='mill',
       llcrnrlat = 7,
       urcrnrlat = 25,
       llcrnrlon = 90,
       urcrnrlon = 120,
       resolution = 'l')
m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawcountries()
m.drawstates()
m.fillcontinents(color='None',lake_color='#FFFFFF')
m.drawmapboundary(color='k', linewidth=1.0, fill_color=None, zorder=None, ax=None)
parallels = np.arange(0.,81,10.)
# labels = [left,right,top,bottom]
m.drawparallels(parallels,labels=[False,True,True,False])
meridians = np.arange(10.,351.,10.)
m.drawmeridians(meridians,labels=[True,False,False,True])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree()))
ax.set_extent([90, 120, 25, 7])
# Set map extent
In_st_shp = 'E:\koppen-master\haidao\haidao.shp'
# provide path of shapefile
state_feature = ShapelyFeature(Reader(In_st_shp).geometries(),
                               crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), edgecolor='k')
ax.add_feature(state_feature, facecolor="none")

plt.show()
```

[haidao.shp](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J_O-SqdO7svZ5jZZYrR0S2neF8NvYCHU/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I frequently do it using Cartopy and I can help you with that. Let me know if you can install cartopy.

Comment: Btw, I found this tutorial for basemap. https://basemaptutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shapefile.html

Comment: Thank you but i cannot download cartopy from cmd. It had some problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working code using cartopy.
Please check the map extent and set the path fo shapefile in the code.

```
import shapefile
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
from cartopy.feature import ShapelyFeature
from cartopy.io.shapereader import Reader
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree()))
ax.set_extent([102, 111, 7, 23])
ax.coastlines(color='black', linewidth=1, resolution='50m')
ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS.with_scale('50m'),
               linestyle='-', alpha=.5)
# Set map extent
In_st_shp = 'Path_to_shape.shp'
# provide path of shapefile
state_feature = ShapelyFeature(Reader(In_st_shp).geometries(),
                               crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), edgecolor='r')
ax.add_feature(state_feature, facecolor="r")
```

Comment: I have some errors : File "E:\koppen-master\CodeDev\123.py", line 5, in <module>
    import cartopy.crs as ccrs
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\cartopy\__init__.py", line 96, in <module>
    import cartopy.crs
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\cartopy\crs.py", line 2418, in <module>

Comment: Seems like cartopy is not installed properly. You have error while importing cartopy.

Comment: Oh i fixed it and it have this error : File "E:\koppen-master\CodeDev\123.py", line 29, in <module>
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=rois[rois]['figsize'],
NameError: name 'rois' is not defined

Comment: Thanks, for pointing this out. That was something specific to my system. I have edited the code. Please use the new one.

Comment: It's work but the result seems to be weird. Btw, thank you so much for your help

Comment: I want to show shapefile on my map. It separate into 2 figures

Comment: Can you show how it looks and what you actually want.

Comment: I have updated my code and my shapefile when run your code. I actually want show this shapefile on my map. It is island groups of Vietnam. I means I want to overlay shapefile on my map.

Comment: Can you please provide me with the shapefile you want to plot. This would help me better understand your problem. E:\koppen-master\haidao\haidao.shp

Comment: I have posted my shapefile already. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Could you help me to solve this problems ? I really appreciate

Comment: Unfortunately the shapefile you provided seems corrupt. I can not open it. However, I have edited my code slightly to meet your needs. Hope it works. Please upvote and accept the answer if that is the case.

Comment: It works. Thank you so much. If i plot coordinate of some points, how can I show them on map ? I'm quite more familiar with basemap and no idea how to plot.

Comment: Great, Please accept the answer if it works and upvote if you like. You can plot coordinates in a way similar to as you plot for matplotlib. ax.scatter(x,y). If you need further help, please ask a separate question as I do not want to further edit my answer here. I fear, further edits will make my answer less relevant.

Comment: I had issues with `ax.set_extent([102, 111, 7, 23])` throwing an exception. I followed the advice in this reported issue, and it solved the issue: https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/1012#issuecomment-360458036